# Taurus distributed load on workers with concurrency

Tags: testing, jmeter, taurus

I'm trying to write a taurus yaml configuration file that will allow me to split 200 threads among two workers. This is the part of the config file for setting this:

```
execution:
- distributed:
  - 172.17.0.2:1099
  - 172.17.0.3:1099
  scenario: scenario
  concurrency: 200
scenarios:
  scenario:
    properties:
      PERFUSER: 400     
    script: /scenarios/scipt.jmx
```

But with this config every worker gets 200 threads. How can I write the config file such that what I specify for concurrency gets distributed equally to all workers (in this case 100 threads for each worker)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Taurus generates a JMeter [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) and kicks off JMeter Master process
2. JMeter master sends the .jmx script to slaves
3. Each slave independently executes the .jmx script and reports the results back to master

Therefore if you define `concurrency` as `200` each slave will execute script with the concurrency of `200`, in case of 2 slaves you will have 400 users, in case of 3 slaves - 600 users, etc.

So you need to manually proportionally reduce the concurrency depending on the number of slave machines.

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)